# Grails create-app name with dot

Tags: grails, grails-3.0

It's a little strange question, but why when I'm running next command:

`grails create-app project.api`

Grails 2.5.0 creates folder `project.api` with main package `project.api`, but Grails 3.0.1 creates folder `api` with package `project` and ignores provided project full name?

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
grails create-app "project.api"
```

Because the dot has special meaning, used to show package hierarchy(my guess).

Comment: Both of this variants don't work, I get same result. I use Windows 8.1, if it does matter.